# Android: SyncAdapter how do I start the auto sync

Tags: android, xamarin, android-syncadapter, synchronization

I have the auto sync running if I select the checkbox through the Setting/Account screen. If I set the UserVisible in the syncadapter.xml to false, I can't select the check box. How to start the auto sync without the option in setting screen.

Answer (score 1):

To manually invoke a sync you call `RequestSync` with at least the Account and Authority string that you have already created for your `SyncAdapter`.

```
ContentResolver.RequestSync(account, authority, null);
```

That will have OS start your registered sync `Service` and thus your `SyncAdapter`.

Re: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#requestSync(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)

Comment: Will it start the periodically sync at the same time?

Comment: @LittleFunny No, you can call `ContentResolver.SetSyncAutomatically(...` if you need to have it start the auto-syncing